# A single pump controlled by a VFD

Tags: power, single-phase, vfd

We're testing a 110V single phase Variable Frequency Drive(VFD) connected to a single pump having randomly let's say: R= 10ohm, L= 50mH. And I am putting these numbers to fiqure out the relationship between the output frequency from the VFD and the power consumption by the pump, so if you could make a curve or giving me the equations used in here I would be thankful.

Comment: The output frequency has little to do with power consumption.  Moving the material is what consumes power, and the consumption depends on what is being moved, it's head, the pump type and capacity... It isn't just the motor characteristics.   And VFD's on single phase motors can work, but you need to be careful of the motor, and they aren't all that efficient.

Comment: You have to be a little specific with VFD's. There is frequency relating to pump rotation ( equivalent to mains supply) Which can be varied to slow or speed up the motor. Then there is switching frequency that is controlling the current to the motor. This is the switching of the IGBT's in a PWM mode to limit current. The motor variables you are adjusting affect the current control algorithms. If the pump can be run slower I believe will save you the most power. The default values for the motor should be used first unless advised by the motor or VFD makers. Then the switching freq may help.

Answer (score 1):

This question is mostly about pump characteristics. The VFDs for single-phase motors that I am aware of do not provide full torque at reduced speeds, so they are suitable only for centrifugal pumps, not for positive displacement pumps. They are also suitable only for permanent split capacitor (PSC) and shaded-pole motors.

The power required to drive a centrifugal pump is given by:
Power = Flow X Pressure X Density / Efficiency X Unit of Measurement Constant.

Reducing the speed of a pump reduces the flow that it can deliver at any given pressure.

The efficiency of a motor powered by a VFD at rated speed and torque is only reduced only slightly below the motor's efficiency with utility power. Single-phase motor efficiencies vary quite a bit depending on power rating and design -- perhaps 60% to over 90%. Reducing the motor's speed and load reduces the efficiency. The efficiency drops gradually at first and then drops more rapidly to zero efficiency at zero speed.

Here are some PowerPoint slides that provide some basic information about VFDs and VFDs used in pump applications. http://vfdriveinfo.com/vfd-training-slides/